# Sum values in a table on click

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I got the task to make a table that has clickable rows that turn green when clicked, it is also supposed to show the value of the `<td>` of the numbers (count) in the green table row, I just can't seem to manage it. How should I approach this matter?

```js
$(function() {
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var countE2 = $("#Value")
  var count = 0;

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
    }
    countEl.html(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Count: <span id="count"> 0</span>
  <br/><br/>
  <table class="table " id="onclick">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>henk</td>
          <td>janssen</td>
          <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>piet</td>
          <td>Paulisma</td>
          <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Theo</td>
          <td>van gogh</td>
          <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Erik</td>
          <td>Doerustig</td>
          <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jan</td>
          <td>de steen</td>
          <td>8</td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I just moved your code into a snippet and it works fine.

Comment: @Archer yes making the text go green works, but counting the value in the count row doesn't work. that is what iam trying to achieve, so like if i'd click the first and the last person the count in the top left would be 9 and those two rows are green. i hope you understand what im trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend calculating the total on-the-fly, rather than keeping a running total, like this...

```js
$(function() {
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var countE2 = $("#Value")

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");

    var count = 0;

    // find all the selected rows and total the values in the 3rd column
    $("tbody tr.green-cell").each(function() {
        count += Number($(this).find("td").eq(2).text());
    });

    countEl.html(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Count: <span id="count"> 0</span>
  <br/><br/>
  <table class="table " id="onclick">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>henk</td>
          <td>janssen</td>
          <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>piet</td>
          <td>Paulisma</td>
          <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Theo</td>
          <td>van gogh</td>
          <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Erik</td>
          <td>Doerustig</td>
          <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jan</td>
          <td>de steen</td>
          <td>8</td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
   $(this).addClass('green-cell');
   var rowCount = 0;
   var valueTotal = 0;
   $('tbody tr.green-cell').each(function(){
        rowCount += 1;
        valueTotal += Number($(this).find('td:last-child').text());
   });
   alert(rowCount);
   alert(valueTotal);
});
```

Comment: OP wants to sum the "Count" column, not actually count the rows.